# Anyone else seeing an error with stellar-dotnet-sdk (AccountResponse - accountId cannot be null)?

Tags: horizon, dotnet-sdk

I've been using stellar-dotnet-sdk for months; today, I get an error while trying to instantiate an AccountResponse object.  `AccountResponse.cs, line 147 (AccountId = accountId ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(accountId), "accountId cannot be null");)`.  My code hasn't changed - I see this error when hitting both the Test and Prod network.

Something is happening while it is trying to parse the JSON returned from horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/….  As I step through the code, the returned JSON looks fine - but the accountID being passed into the Signer object constructor is null (haven't stepped back further to see the root of all of this).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must update your SDK since we didn't have support for horizon 0.17.0 that was released 2 / 3 days ago.

Also with the new SDK you should use keyPair.AccountId instead of only keyPair.

Apologies, let us know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks - that looks to be it.  I went ahead and download/compiled latest source, will wait for Nuget package to be released at some point in the future.

Comment: Latest NuGet is out, I also changed how we release. I use to manually deploy NuGet, now NuGet package is built from master source and immediately deployed so you won't have to build from source again. Sorry about that pain there I hope doing it this way alleviates it in future.